# Proving the conservation of 4-momentum for a particle collision $A+B\to C+D$

Tags: special-relativity, conservation-laws, collision, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

Let me say that particle A hits particle B and two particles come out - C and D;

In system S I can write: $$p_A^μ+p_B^μ=p_C^μ+p_D^μ;\tag{1}$$ here $p_N^μ$ is the 4-momentum.

Using the Lorentz transformation I want to prove that energy and momentum are also conserved in frame S'.
I rewrite $(1)$ like that:
$$p_A^μ+p_B^μ-p_C^μ-p_D^μ=0; (2)$$

Now I write something similar for the system S', except I do not know yet whether it's equal to zero:
$$p_A^{'μ}+p_B^{'μ}-p_C^{'μ}-p_D^{'μ}=C;(3)$$

My goal is to find  that $C=0$;

I know that for Lorentz transformations this holds true: 
$$p^{'μ}=Λ_ν^{μ}p^ν ;(4)$$

So if I put (4) into (3) , I get
$$Λ_ν^{μ}p_A^{ν}+Λ_ν^{μ}p_B^{ν}-Λ_ν^{μ}p_C^{ν}-Λ_ν^{μ}p_D^{ν}=C;(5)$$

Now, this will be my question, if I consider each particle's transformation $Λ_ν^{μ}$ to be the same, I can bring out the common factor $Λ_ν^{μ}(p_A^{ν}+p_B^{ν}-p_C^{ν}-p_D^{ν})$ (6) and inside the parentheses I have the same equation (2), thus $C=0$ and 4-momentum is conserved.

My questions are: 
1) Why can I consider that $Λ_ν^{μ}$ is the same for every particle's transformation?

2) Also, is my method of proving the 4-momentum conservation alright, or am I doing something ineffectively?

Comment: 1) Because $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ depends on the relative velocity between the _frames_ (and not the particles). 2) It's alright, but you could also have noted that for any frame $S'$ obtained by Lorentz-boosting the frame $S$, you would get $C=\Lambda^\mu_\nu 0=0$.

Comment: @Demosthene Why write this as a comment?

Comment: the sum of time-like four momentums is always time-like. This is proved with the Schwartz inequality

Comment: you use the Schwartz inequality to prove that time-like four vectors are a group with the vector addition operation

Comment: What level of answer are you expecting? I don't really understand your confusion.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I'm doing everything correctly. As far as I understand user Demosthene gave the reason I was asking for, so I guess I understand it now.

My confusion was, that I didn't fully understand the exact reason why $Λ^μ_ν$ is the same for every particle, even though it had to be.

Comment: Great, well maybe somebody will add something, but if not, did you know that you can answer your own question?

Comment: I will do that, alright

Comment: Henrikas: Re-writing your eq. (1) a little more careful than you did, I get instead: $$p_A^{\mu}+p_B^{\mu}-p_C^{\mu}-p_D^{\mu} = 0^{\mu}\tag{2~},$$
and consequently your eq. (6) evaluates rather more consistently: $$\Lambda^{\nu}_{\mu}~(p_A^{\mu}+p_B^{\mu}-p_C^{\mu}-p_D^{\mu}) = \Lambda^{\nu}_{\mu}~0^{\mu} = 0^{\nu}. \tag{6~ }$$"_am I doing something ineffectively?_" -- Yes: you could obviously leave off the "primes" in your eqs. (3) and (4) [... contd.]

Comment: Noting that "$\mu$" and "$\nu$" are distinctive reference base indices, corresponding to the two reference systems under consideration, you could write more effectively:  $$p_A^{\nu} + p_B^{\nu} - p_C^{\nu} - p_D^{\nu} = C^{\nu} \tag{3~},$$
with the goal of proving "$C^{\nu} = 0^{\nu}$"; and $$p^{\nu} = \Lambda^{\nu}_{\mu}~p^{\mu}. \tag{4~}$$

Answer (score 1):

To answer my question #1:

As Demosthene said, $Λ^μ_ν$ depends only on the relative velocity between frames $S$ and $S'$, but not the relative velocity between particles. This allows me to make the assumption, which I numbered 6 in my initial question, thus solving my problem.

Comment: And to answer your question #2. This method is so trivial that it is difficult to say whether it can be simplified or not. I would just say that Lorentz transformations are linear and therefore preserve zero linear combinations of vectors.